# surroundContents() make changes `live`?

Tags: javascript, html, range

Links to live examples @ [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cEsKy/) & [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/inapiy/edit#preview).

So this function:

```
function symbolize(e){
    var elements = e.childNodes; // text nodes are necessary!
    console.log(elements);
    for(var i=0; i < elements.length; i++){
        t = elements[i];
        var range = document.createRange(), offset = 0, length = t.nodeValue.length;
        while(offset < length){
            range.setStart(t, offset); range.setEnd(t, offset + 1);
            range.surroundContents(document.createElement('symbol'));
            offset++;
        }
    }
}
```

..should iterate over every letter and wrap it in a `<symbol/>` element. But it doesn't seem to be working.

So I added the `console.log();` right after the `*.childNodes` have been fetched, but as you'll see in the example site above, the log contains 2 unexpected elements in front(!) of the array. And yeah, because of this, I have a feeling that `surroundContents();` make the changes live(!). *couldn't find any reference on this though*

One of the elements is an empty `Text` node, the other is my `<symbol/>`. But yeah, this is totally unexpected result and messes up the rest of the function.

What could be wrong with it?

Thanks in advance!

### Update

Oh, looks like the elements are added on Chrome, Firefox doesn't add the elements, but still halts the function.

Comment: How is jsfiddle too much of a hassle? I love it!

Comment: @Juan, it's slow over here (and no, the internet works flawlessly). Plus I tried copying the functions, and `window.onload` didn't work over at Fiddle's place.

Comment: Yeah, I tried creating it for you but jsfiddle was dead. In any case, I think the question is answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Element.childNodes is indeed a live list , it could not be otherwise (that would mean an incorrect list of nodes). The easiest solution is to freeze (make a copy of) it before you mess with it (by surrounding existing ranges).

```
var elements = Array.prototype.slice.call(e.childNodes, 0);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/childNodes it's of type NodeList
https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/NodeList those are live lists

Comment: Ah, would be awesome if browser log would display some kind of identifier next to an element if it's `live`. Thanks!

Comment: I disagree with you.True that it's not obvious that document.getElementsByTagName('p') returns a live list. However, childNodes would not make sense if it were not live. Most would consider it a bug that childNodes does not update correctly as you insert new children.